# Dual Boot back to Windows 10 only. BIOS settings

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uninstall, windows-10

I have a Dell Inspiron 7460 laptop wich originally had Windows 10 installed. I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 as dual boot, but had some problems with nvidia drivers and decided to give up on using ubuntu on this computer.

The installation was made following the guide on [this link](http://www.dell.com/support/article/br/pt/brbsdt1/SLN301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-a-recent-windows-operating-system-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN) and I have installed other Linux Kernels and upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.2 after.

I want to remove linux and grub, so the computer boots Windows 10 directly. But there are two questions that I wasn't able to find by searching:

- Most things I read suggested booting from Windows installation device and using the `BootRec.exe /fixmbr` command. Does this work for every computer? Do I have to change any BIOS settings (I'm not sure if I've changed any during installation, but Dell's guide tells to have some specific stettings wich I'm not sure if they are the original).
- After I've uninstalled everything Linux related, how can I get the HDD space back to the Windows partition? The image below shows what the partitions look like, but I can't tell wich ones are Linux related and can be formatted after.[Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkdUd.png)

Comment: yes, fixmbr will put windows bootloader back in the mbr, all the partitins that are not ntfs are linux

Comment: If UEFI : http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi